# Unity - Type mismatch when adding objects to Generic List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I have an abstract class called `RunTimeSet<T>`:

```
public abstract class RuntimeSet<T> : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<T> items = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        if(!items.Contains(t)) items.Add(t);
    }
    public void Remove(T t)
    {
        if (!items.Contains(t)) items.Remove(t);
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a class that extends this, and stores GameObjects:

```
public class BuildingSet : RuntimeSet<GameObject>
{
    //...
}

static class BuildingSetMenu
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Create/Sets/BuildingSet")]
    public static void CreateRuntimeSet()
    {
        var asset = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<BuildingSet>();

        var path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(Selection.activeObject);
        path += "/My New BuildingSet.asset";

        ProjectWindowUtil.CreateAsset(asset, path);
    }
}
```

Then in my Building I keep a reference to this Scriptable Object, and call:

```
public void OnEnable()
    {
        buildingSet.Add(gameObject);
    }
```

However, in my Editor it shows as "Type mismatch" for each entry in the List, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScriptableObject`s are assets, [designed to hold only data, independent of game objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html). They cannot permanently store references to game objects within a specific Scene, as these would not make sense for any other Scene the `ScriptableObject` may be referenced from, similarly to how a Prefab cannot reference the contents of a specific Scene prior to being placed. Game objects referenced by them will therefor be listed as being of an incorrect type, and any such references will be listed as missing upon Scene change.

Comment: Are you sure that is true? https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2572&v=raQ3iHhE_Kk. Take a look at runtime sets @40:00

Comment: @Green_qaue I have edited my answer to clarify, Scene-specific objects can be stored temporarily in such a way (and other scripts can interact with the objects referenced in these lists as normal), but changing Scene will break any references still stored in the list.